# Is Stack Exchange network slowly falling apart?

Tags: discussion

Though, I think I made may homework quite good and read through about pages for [Mathematics](https://math.stackexchange.com/tour) and [MathOverflow](https://mathoverflow.net/tour), I still have no idea, what is the difference between these two sites and what is the purpose to keep them separate, instead of integrating them together?

Again, since both [Mathematics](https://math.stackexchange.com/) and [History](https://history.stackexchange.com/) exists, I have no idea, what is a reason for proposing [History of Science and Mathematics](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/65204/history-of-science-and-mathematics)? Why questions and answers about history of science and matehematics can't be asked in two former sites?

Not mentioning, that there are currently about five or more sites about pure programming. One for developers pros of particular language, one for developers in general, one for development contests one for development homeworks etc. etc. Are there any limits to this?

I understand, that we (many of us) want to have *a lot* of sites in Stack Exchange network. But, aren't we passing some thin border, that we shouldn't pass through? Isn't Stack Exchange network slowly falling apart? How many different sites about each one, single field of expertise we want?

Comment: Couldn't you have picked a less dramatic title?

Comment: You're tearing me apart, trejder!

Comment: Couldn't you both come up with more valuable, less pointless comments? And yes... less dramatic title wouldn't bring so much attention.

Comment: It could be argued that a dramatic title for such an undramatic issue provides unwanted attention.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Mathematics SE and Math Overflow were not created this way by SE, Math Overflow was independent and just recently moved into the SE network. It's actually not that hard to figure out on which site you should ask, MO is for *research-level* mathematics only. If you aren't working on your PhD in mathematics, already have one or are a professor, you probably shouldn't ask your mathematics question on MO (there are certainly exceptions to this rule).

The division of SE sites is much more about communities than about topics. Ubuntu got their own site because they have an existing community that thinks of themselves as "Ubuntu users", and not necessarily generic "Linux users".

Stack Exchange doesn't create sites that are complete subsets of existing site, where every single question would be on-topic on another site. This prevents a significant amount of possible sites that would split the communities, but it still allows for sites with a large amount of overlap.

The SE network isn't centrally planned, but created by different communities. This won't lead to the most efficient separation of topics, but it ensures that there is a community that cares about the site for each one. A certain amount of duplication and overlap is the inevitable price to pay for having the whole process initiated and guided by the community.

I personally don't think the "History of Mathematics and Science" site would work, it seems to small of a topic to me. But it's not my decision, and I generally don't worry too much about A51 proposals. The site still has to prove during private beta that it is viable.

Comment: Thank you for your professional and really enlightening answer.

Comment: Isn't it interesting that a question that has been massively downvoted recieves and thus deserves (?) such a reasonable and constructive answer? Maybe something could thus be said about downvoting behavior? Especially if DVs not even bother to give reasons other than "title too dramatic".